# OfType ForEach exclude particular elements

Tags: c#, foreach, oftype

I have a line of code that clears all labels from the form

```
Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().ForEach(p => p.Visible = false);
```

Now I need to exclude particular labels(either by id or text) from that list (like title labels). Is there a way to do so by modifying that line of code alone? I found out about Where(), though I am not sure about the syntax that goes inside those brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(lbl => lbl.Title != "something").ToList().ForEach(p => p.Visible = false);
```

Comment: Removed my answer, yours is more concise.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you! I tried something similar, it looks like I was simply missing minor syntax.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I wanted to mark your answer straight away, but there was a time limit before I could accept answer. I should be able to do so by the time I post that comment =)